# How to add new button in Backpack laravel?

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-backpack, laravel-backpack-5

How to add a relationship button in list operation?

Post has many comments, I want to add button (like preview) in the Post list to view all the comments.

Post table

- id(PK)
- title
- description

Comments

- id(PK)
- comment
- post_id(FK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following article. It can help you set this:

https://backpackforlaravel.com/articles/tutorials/nested-resources-in-backpack-crud